# UITableView with auto height in iOS 8

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autolayout, height

Before iOS 8 (and it's SDK) I did auto height of UITableViewCell using this delegate method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (!_prototypeCell)
    {
        _prototypeCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyShowIdentifier"];
    }

    EventShow *show = self.myShows[indexPath.row];

    self.prototypeCell.categoryNameLabel.text = show.event.category.name;
    self.prototypeCell.eventNameLabel.text = show.event.title;

    [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

    return size.height + 1.0f;
}
```

My cell has two labels, one on top of the other with autolayout constraints telling the labels to grow vertically as much as the want. Everything worked fine.

After iOS 8 came, I get an "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" error ONLY THE FIRST TIME THE METHOD systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: IS EXECUTED. The delegate method is called 3 times. This is the detail of the error:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1e8ebce30 H:|-(5)-[UILabel:0x7fd1eb0e00a0'Cine']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd1eb0c0210 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1eb06b120 H:[UILabel:0x7fd1eb0e00a0'Cine']-(5)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd1eb0c0210 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1e8e7be50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd1eb0c0210(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd1eb06b120 H:[UILabel:0x7fd1eb0e00a0'Cine']-(5)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd1eb0c0210 )>
```

There is a new constraint there called "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height" with is set to zero. I don't now what that is, but I'm sure it should be > 0.

The auto height still works in iOS 8, but it throws this error that i can't fix.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is for width of label as you had set specific width and you also set leading and trailing constraint. So what is happening here is to label is breaking leading,trailing or width constraint to satisfy trailing constraint of label.

But to satisfy your constraint for trailing it will break width constraint.

What you need to do here is just set leading,top, trailing and bottom constraint to both the label. Also you need to set vertical spacing between those label and no need to set height and width constraints to both label.

Also in attribute inspector you set lines = 0, Line Breaks = Word Wrap.

you also need to set “self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;” in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Wow, I'm so sorry, I copied the wrong error (edited). Instead of UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width it's UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height. The answer still applies? Thanks and sorry again.